# FOSRestBundle double leading slash in route

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to handle a wrongly coded leading slash route in an Android application. It is trying to reach our system using:

```
//api/1.0/store/products/video/USD.json
```

but should normaly be

```
/api/1.0/store/products/video/USD.json
```

so this is causing a route not found exception in our app.

**I cannot change the android application! I must find a way to make the wrong route work!**

What i've tried:

- Splitting the controller in two, one with the standard "/api" prefix and one with a prefix of "//api", didn't work, i think FOSRestBundle is fixing that for me live, so all my routes are still only 1 leading slash
- Using a rewrite rule in .htaccess (See below) to rewrite the rule before  i get problems, this would be the best strategy as it would keep my app and integration tests clean

Attempt using HTACCESS

```
RewriteRule /api/(.*) api/$1 [L]
```

This rule is supposed to work if i test it on "http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/" but in my htaccess it doesn't. Here's the content of my .htaccess.

Can anyone help me figure out a solution?

---

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite double leading slash routes to single leading slash routes
    RewriteRule /api/(.*) api/$1 [L]

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I tried, and failed to match the requested uri, so I will suggest you different approach, if you find it suitable. How about if we just replace all double leading slashes with single ones?

What I mean is something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

The following tests on my project were successful:

```
/admin//orders => /admin/orders
//admin//orders//5 => /admin/orders/5
```

And lastly, I pasted yours as well:

```
//api/1.0/store/products/video/USD.json
```

gave this:

```
No route found for "GET /api/1.0/store/products/video/USD.json"
```

which is I believe what we are looking for. Hope you can use this solution as a temporary one until someone else provides a better one.

Comment: I eventually got there too and found practically the same thing somewhere else on the net and it worked up to the point that the android application was not built to support redirect and kept crashing.

Comment: We held a meeting and decided to simply break backward compatibility with V1 and force people to update to V1.0.1 until V2 is available a few months later.

Comment: I'll upvote and mark as anwser as it is truly the right anwser but not for the exact case that i have, because of the comm layer of the app. For anyone else, this should work!

Comment: Ah... I was hoping that the application would've recognize the redirects. Sorry I was not much of a help, and thanks for the upvote.